# Prove if $a|c$ and $b|d$ and $\gcd(c,d)=1$ then $\gcd(a,b)=1$

Tags: divisibility

I'm trying to prove that if $a|c$ and $b|d$ and $\gcd(c,d)=1$ then $\gcd(a,b)=1$

So far, I have assumed that:

Since $\gcd(c,d) = 1$ then by EEA, $$\gcd(c,d) = 1 = cx + dy$$ for some $x,y$ that are integers.
And since $a|c$ and $b|d$ then $c=am$ and $d=br$ for some $m,r$ that are integers.

I just don't know where to go from here. Thanks you.

Comment: Hint: $amx + bry = (mx)a + (ry)b = 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're really close to the answer! As of now, you have the three equations (for integer $x,y,m,r$)
$$1=cx+dy$$
$$c=am$$
$$d=br$$
The only thing you need do from there is to substitute the last two equations into the first one - that is, get
$$1=(am)x+(br)y$$
$$1=a(mx)+b(ry)$$
and, hey presto, we have a sum of $a$ and $b$ with integer coefficients $mx$ and $ry$ equaling $1$, so they must be coprime.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $gcd(a,b)|a$, $gcd(a,b)|b$, hence $gcd(a,b)$ divides both $c$ and $d$...

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**.  Let $g$ be a (positive) common factor of $a$ and $b$.  Our aim is to show that $g$ has to be $1$, no other possibility.

In view of the information given, can you see how $g$ is related to $a$?  Can you see how it is related to $b$?  Can you then solve the problem?